# Bootstrap 3: Toggle above logo in mobile view

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get my logo to resive proportionately to a bootstrap design. Unfortunately it never looks right. I don't like that the toggle sits on top of the logo (inflating the header more than it needs to be. I would like to have it in line. Please see screenshot)

[image: ScreenShot of Site]

I have tried using media queries to sort this out with no success and changing its layout to absolute, however, the logo no longer scales to the navbar size once this has happened. See the code I was using.

**CSS**

```
@media(min-width:1000px){ 

    header img{
        max-width: 100%; 
        height: auto; 
        position: relative; 
        padding-left:80px;
    }

}

@media(max-width:999px){ 

    header img{
        width: 100%; 
        height: auto; 
        left:0;
        top:0;
        position: relative; 
        z-index: -999;
        padding-bottom: 40px; 
    }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: ( You should create a demo like bootply )

Answer (score 1):

The solution for logo in the navbar are all different because it depends on the image itself and its aspect ratio. Since you don't have any links in that navbar html and the min-width is not addressed in the question, the following demo link and css is a good starting point. Also, when you use a fixed navbar the padding of the body class is usually the height of the navbar plus some extra, since a responsive image changes height, there's a script that calculates it on resize/load.

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/iDeTaFO/1/edit?html,css,js,output**

```
   .navbar-brand {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 70px 0 15px;
    }
    /* logo image on mobile */
    .navbar-brand img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        position: absolute;
        float: none;
        right: 0;
        top: 5px;
    }
    @media (min-width:768px) { 
        .navbar-brand {
            float: none;
            width: auto;
      max-height:none;
            padding: 0!important;
        }
        .navbar-header {
            float: left;
            margin: 0;
            width: 30%;
        }
        /* logo image */
        .navbar-brand img {
            margin: 0;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: none;
        }
        .nav.navbar-nav li.active a,
        .nav.navbar-nav li.active a:hover {
            background: transparent
        }
        #nav-collapse {
            float: right;
            padding: 0!important;
            margin: 0!important;
            width: 70%;
        }
    }
```